# Firefox : Difference between window, document, document.content & content

Tags: firefox, architecture, scope

Developing an extension in Firefox and seems my mistakes are stemming from the fact that I don't understand the differences between what the below mean.

Would be great if someone could point, when exactly to use them.

Can someone who has worked with Firefox explain it please. I've added what I understand and they might very well be completely incorrect -

**window**
**document** = XUL elements + ( Web page of the current open tab)
**document.content**
**content.document** = The content of the web page of the tab open. Does not include the xul elements.
**top.window.content**

I'll collect the the correct explanation for the answers and put them in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an extension, `document` is the XUL document for the browser's UI.  `window` is the window for that document (the object used as the script global for the chrome JS, etc).  `content.document` is the document object for the web page in the currently selected tab.  `content` is the window object for the web page in the currently selected tab.

Comment: Still a bit unclear on "window". If "document" is the root object that encapsulates everything, then shouldn't it be the one having all the other stylesheets + JS inside of it ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say " window is the window for that document" ?

Comment: Most simply, `document` is the root node in the DOM; it does not "encapsulate everything".  `window` is the scope object for scripts.  So if in a script you do `foo = 5` that sets `window.foo` to 5.  And when in a script you write `document` you're actually getting `window.document`.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, one more question though, what does top.window.content mean ?

Comment: `top` means the thing at the top of the parent chain of the window the script is running on.  If the script is not running in a subframe, then `top == window`.  `top.window == top` in all cases, so that `.window` is just redundant.  For the Firefox toplevel window, `.content` returns the window of the currently selected tab.  So `top.window.content` will give you the window of the currently selected tab if running in the Firefox UI.